# work on a repository from a different organization devOps

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Is there a way to work on a repository from a different organization in devOps? I want to link the changes to items in organization 1 (for manage) but when a pull request is made I want to update the repository in organization 2. (Org 2 has the orignal repo)

(I need to have the repo in org 2, but all the management,changes and pull requests needs to be done in org1)

Could be 2 diferent repositories and update both every time a change is made in one or could be just using the one in both organization, any of this works for me.

I tried importing the repo from org2 in 1 but what it does is cloning it so when I do a change on org1 is not being updated in original repo from org 2.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will provide an example for these two repos in the same org.

1.The two repos need to have the same structure. So the first step is to new a repo and import from "for manage repo", rename the new repo to "original repo".

[image]

2.Create a pipeline and select source repo as "for manage repo"

YAML Sample:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git clone --bare https://PAT@dev.azure.com/{Org Name}}/{Proj Name}}/_git/{for manage repo name}
      cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)/{for manage repo name}.git
      git remote add origin1 https://PAT@dev.azure.com/{Org Name}}/{Proj Name}}/_git/{original repo name}
      git push -u origin1  --all
```

3.Evety time a change is made to "for manage repo", the pipeline will be triggered and push this change to "original repo".

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you, that worked even for the repos of projects in different organizatons. Thanks!!