# Import azure devops code from one repository to another repository in same project

Tags: azure-devops, repository

I am importing the code from one azure Devops repository to another repository in same project. while doing source code import to new repository. Import file option is not there.
workaround I did is below-

1. I cleaned the new Repository and then from old source code repository cloned the URL. used this URL to import in new repository -> File option -> import. Import option didn't appear. doc link here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#import-into-an-existing-empty-repo
2. used the power shell script from this Microsoft documentation- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#manually-import-a-repo-using-az-repos-cli . using this script getting error  "The User aaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaa is not authorized to access this resource".

Can you please guide me to steps to move code from one repo to another in azure Devops?
Thank you!

Comment: Look up how to mirror a Git repo. It's literally three Git CLI commands.

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the current repo to a new one both using "git commands" and from Azure DevOps UI. Please make sure the structure of both repos are the same and you have the corresponding permission to act with code in Azure DevOps.

1.From DevOps UI (Git as an example)

Paste the original repo's URL from browser:

[https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjName}/_git/{OriginalRepoName}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrgName%7D/%7BProjName%7D/_git/%7BOriginalRepoName%7D)

[image]

Using DevOps PAT for authentication.

[image]

[image]

2.For Git commands, you could refer to this link for details: [work on a repository from a different organization devOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73395881/work-on-a-repository-from-a-different-organization-devops/73399700#73399700)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already performed all the steps which you mentioned above, but the problem with that is, the Name field should have the repo name which does not exist. In my case I already have the New empty repo, when I give that repo name while import, it says the repository already exist. It was not fulfilling my purpose as I wanted to import the code from old repo(which has source code) to new repo(already created and empty). I hope this clarifies my requirement.

Comment: Username + password didn't work for me. But the Personal Access Token (PAT) did indeed work. How to create one can be seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows

Answer (score -1):

I'm not understanding why you need a special "import option" for this. Maybe you mean something by "import" that I'm not understanding? Why can't you just:

Check out both SourceRepo and DestRepo to your workstation.

Copy the source code from your SourceRepo working folder to your DestRepo working folder.

Commit and push DestRepo.

Comment: As I am doing this in Azure DevOps, and we can't clone the source code on our local machines as per the organization policy.